# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'present' - how to invoke 'present'?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, segue

i have a uiview file that i embedded into my tableview header

(class TopHeader: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource)

If I use `present(_:animated:completion:)` i am getting: Value of type `TopHeader` has no member 'present'
(  self.present(MyOtherViewController(doModes: [.photo]),  animated: true, completion: nil))

How can I use the present method from there? Can I call a function that is in my uiviewcontroller from this uiview file?

Comment: a `UIView` it is not the same as a `UIViewController`

Comment: self.parentContainerViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `present(_:animated:completion)` because it is a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIView`.

You shouldn't be presenting view controllers from views directly. If you need this behavior, it would be better to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UIView` since the view controller will contain a `view` within it anyway.

Comment: so how can i connect my button(is in the uiview xib) there?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I call a function that is in my uiviewcontroller from this uiview file?

Yes, if the view is in the view controller hierarchy, you can recursively get the `next` responder until you reach the owning view controller.

Comment: how can i delegate corectly? i am using separate xib file for the tableview header.

Answer (score 0):

The `present(_:animated:completion:)` method is a method of `UIViewController`, not `UIView`. You need to figure out a way to pass the request to your view controller. The usual pattern is to define a protocol that lets the view as the view controller to display another view controller. Then set up your view to have the view controller as a delegate that conforms to that protocol.

Comment: I couldn't find a code snippet about this. Is there no way i can do this without protocols?